# UILabel Adjust size to size of array

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, uilabel

I've tried everything and just can't seem to make it work. I have a array called "HomePlayersString"(not ideal to call it string since its an array i know) This array contains a number of short strings. the strings are separated by a /n so they should be printed on each line in the label. The thing is i just cant seem to make the Label resize to the size of the NSArray.

Here is the code I've come up with from void viewdidload

```
HomePlayersLabel.text = [HomePlayersString componentsJoinedByString:@"\n"];
[HomePlayersLabel setNumberOfLines:0];
[HomePlayersLabel sizeToFit];
CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(296, FLT_MAX);

CGSize expectedLabelSize = [HomePlayersString sizeWithFont:HomePlayersLabel.font constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize lineBreakMode:HomePlayersLabel.lineBreakMode];

CGRect newFrame = HomePlayersLabel.frame;
newFrame.size.height = expectedLabelSize.height;
HomePlayersLabel.frame = newFrame;
```

The error I get is following:

```
no visible @interface for 'NSArray' declared the selector 'sizewithfont:contrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:'
```

Comment: Please stop naming all of your variable like classes. Variable and method names should begin with loewrcase letters. Using standard conventions makes your code easier to read by others.

Comment: It would also be good to name your variables with names that makes sense -- calling an array HomePlayersString is confusing. It appears that it even confused you, since you're trying to use a string method (sizeWithFont) with it.

Answer (score 2):

The sizeWithFont: variants are members of the NSString UIKit Additions: https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html

So you'll need to send it to `HomePlayerLabel.text` as in

```
CGSize expectedLabelSize = [HomePlayersLabel.text sizeWithFont:HomePlayersLabel.font constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize lineBreakMode:HomePlayersLabel.lineBreakMode];
```

Comment: This may not affect you, but keep in mind that `sizeWithFont:` is actually an approximation and may not get the line heights perfectly when working with many lines (also when working with non-latin character languages).